# Is there any explanation for some random upvote marathons?

Tags: discussion, voting

Maybe once a month,  I just get a random boost of maybe 15 upvotes in a very short timeframe (about an hour). Looks like somebody just ran down my question/answers and threw upvotes on everything. (Questions seem unrelated on category/score, I seem to be the only link between them all)

[image]

Really wonder where are these coming from? Any explanation? Bots trying to seem human by giving upvotes to a random human user or something like it?

Also is it something Arqade/SE should look to eliminate?

Comment: There is likely no explanation other than sometimes people serially vote by tag, or they might have liked something else you did and voted on other things you did as well as weird sort of reward, etc. SE does have stuff in place to catch serial votes, if they meet certain criteria (which, obviously, are not explained in detail to avoid people gaming the system).

Comment: It looks like serial votes.  Those same posts listed in your picture I received upvotes for as well around that same time (I think I answered some of your questions).

Comment: Sometimes when I'm bored I look through old questions of my favorite tags and vote on them and their answers and it sometimes maxes out my daily vote limit within a short time. This case looks like someone could have done that too.

Answer (score 9):

I can answer this one because I've done it before.

Usually when I go into my backlog to play a game I'll search the tag and check out some of the questions. If I have similar questions or I think they are interesting I will throw them an upvote.

A lot of the time it's the same person asking the question, so that's why you might see such activity.

Example: I went and played Bioshock Infinite recently and there were a lot of config questions that I was also wondering about and I upvoted a bunch because they were relevant to me.

This may or not be what happened to you exactly, but it's an account of an instance where this might happen to someone.

Comment: I edited my question maybe while you were answering... but look at my upvotes. There's questions about Breath of the Wild, Minecraft, SNES Classic, Amiibos, Mario 64, etc. The link between them all seem to be me and only me.

Comment: @Fredy31 Ah yeah I see that. I don't really have an explanation for something like that - seems like you have an admirer!

Comment: I also feel as if the badges for `x votes` could be related as someone would browse a game they know and up vote good questions and answers. We are a gaming community after all.